# Security Scanner Results shows asserts needed for mock class.Is it mandatory?

Tags: webservicemock

We made a security scan through 'Force.com Security Scanner' which says that asserts  are mandatory for mock class.But we have used asserts for all the test classes which makes use of those mocks.I would like to know whether asserts are needed for mock?if so,How can we implement it?

Comment: Can you annotate your mock class with @isTest to indicate that it's only used for test purposes? Perhaps if you do that and rerun the scanner the error will go away

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not necessary.

You cad add an exception comment page to your submission explaining why you feel items found int he report are false positives.

When you create this sheet, be specific

For Example:

**Item:** 1-1 - Asserts Required - This is a Mock Class marked with @isTest so it is excluded from code coverage requirements. It is not an actual test class but is only available during test execution and thus does not require asserts.